# Funcionamiento de arrays y generacion de aleatorios

Tags: java, array, math

Estoy intentando resolver el siguiente ejercicio:

- Crear un vector de números enteros de un tamaño aleatorio comprendido entre 10 y 50 elementos.
  • Llenar el vector con números aleatorios comprendidos entre -100 y 100 sin repetir ninguno.
  • Crear un segundo vector que contenga los elementos del anterior almacenados en orden inverso.
  • Mostrar ambos vectores en la consola.

Mi programa no funciona, porque no me rellena el array con el rango especificado y no entiendo el porqué. Ya que si pruebo `(int)(Math.random()*(100-(-100))-100);` por separado, me genera aleatorios sin repetirse entre -100 y 100.

Os paso el código por si me podéis aclarar las dudas. Muchísimas gracias.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
        //generar indice para los vectores
        int indice = (int)(Math.random()*(100-50)+50);
        int [] vector1 = new int [indice];
        int [] vector2 = new int [indice];

        
        for (int i=0; i<vector1.length;i++) {
            vector1[i]= (int)(Math.random()*(100-(-100))-100);
        }//relleno vector1 con numeros [-100 y 100]
        
        int numero = vector1.length-1;// para rellenar el vector 2
        for (int i=vector1.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
            vector2 [(i-numero)*(-1)] = vector1[i];
        }// relleno vector2 
        System.out.println("Vector 1:"); //imprimo vector1
        for (int i = 0; i<vector1.length;i++) {
            System.out.print(vector1[i]+"");
        }
        System.out.println("\nVector 2:"); // imprimo vector 2
        for (int i = 0; i<vector2.length;i++) {
            System.out.print(vector2[i]+"");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La razón de tu conflicto es por que estas haciendo uso de `print()` al concatenar el valor de cada posición del array los haces con `("")`espacio cerrado,debes darle un espacio abierto `(" ")` , es por eso que te arroja valores descomunales a la vista al momento de imprimir.

```
System.out.print(vector1[i]+" ");
```

ahora esta linea de código solo te devuelve números aleatorios,eso no quiere decir que al momento de llenarlo en el array un numero x que ya se genero no vuelva a generarse

```
vector1[i]= (int)(Math.random()*(100-(-100))-100);
```

Recomendación:
para ello podrías crear un método que genere números aleatorios,para facilitar la sintaxis

```
public static int generarNumeroAleatorio(int inicio,int tope){
        
       int num=(int)Math.floor(Math.random()*(tope-inicio+1)+(inicio));

       return num;
   }
```

y al momento de llenarlos en el array de tamaño random,ir condicionando cada valor para que este no se encuentre en una posición ya ingresada

```
int indice = generarNumeroAleatorio(10,50);
int[]vector=new int[indice];

 for(int j=0;j<vector.length;j++){
            boolean encontrado = false;
            int aleatorio=generarNumeroAleatorio(-100,100);
            for (int k=0;k<j ;k++){
                if(vector[k]==aleatorio){
                    encontrado=true;
                }
            }
            if(!encontrado){
                vector[j]=aleatorio;
            }else{
                j--;
            }
        }
```

Fuente:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta. Funcionó correctamente y con el método mucho mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Esta línea es extraña:

```
int indice = (int)(Math.random()*(100-50)+50);
```

Porque a causa de los paréntesis, es equivalente a

```
int indice = (int)(Math.random()*50+50);
```

Que te va a dar un valor entre 50 y 100

Quizá te sea más cómodo crear primero un método que te de valores aleatorios entre dos límites. Si puedes usar en tu ejercicio la clase `java.util.Random` podrías hacer algo como

```
var random = new Random();
int indice = random.nextInt(41) + 10; //[0..40] + 10
```

y para generar números entre -100 y 100 podrías hacer algo como

```
int valor = random.nextInt(201) - 100; //[0..200) - 100
```

Y, en cualquier caso, no puedes asegurar que los números no se repitan al generarse, es como tirar un dado. Por tanto tendrás que recorrer el array entero cada vez para saber que no se han repetido... o guardar los números en un `Set` (que no admite elementos repetidos) hasta tener la cantidad necesaria y entonces copiarlos en un array.